# gcloud cli filter format and limit behaviour

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

I experience a very strange behaviour with the `--filter` `--format`and `--limit` flags.

I have the following command:

```
gcloud run revisions list --sort-by=~creationTimestamp --service "api-gateway" --platform managed --format="value(metadata.name)" --filter="spec.containers.env.name=ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME"
```

The command returns me this list with in total 177 items:

```
api-gateway-00295-xeb  2020-07-21T06:46:14.991421Z
api-gateway-00283-wug   2020-07-20T14:41:02.108809Z
api-gateway-00281-yix   2020-07-20T14:32:17.325634Z
api-gateway-00278-ham   2020-07-20T12:50:13.385984Z
api-gateway-00276-mol   2020-07-17T12:21:36.897245Z
api-gateway-00274-nih   2020-07-16T07:50:18.544546Z
api-gateway-00272-kol   2020-07-13T12:55:35.485589Z
api-gateway-00270-vis   2020-07-13T08:38:52.352422Z
api-gateway-00263-zaf   2020-07-10T14:08:36.502972Z
...
```

The first thing is, that the timestamp is returned for a strange reason. (I actually state what I want to get with `--format` and when I remove the `--sort-by` flag the timestamp is gone.)

Secondly, when I add `--limit 1` no result is returned at all!

```
gcloud run revisions list --sort-by=~creationTimestamp --service "api-gateway" --platform managed --format="value(metadata.name)" --filter="spec.containers.env.name=ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" --limit 1
```

With `--limit 5` only two are returned, so as a result it cloud be that the limit is applied before filtering, although the documentation says that is should be the other way around.
However the "latest" entry is `api-gateway-00295-xeb` and should be returned with a limit of 1.

I don't understand the behaviour of the gcloud CLI here.

Does anyone have explanations for the two things?

Comment: Both "smell" like bugs. I recommend you file this on Google's Issue Tracker for Cloud SDK: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102

Comment: One problem with CLI-specific filtering and formatting is the need to learn each CLI command's proprietary mechanism. An alternative is to pump the output to JSON and then use a general-purpose tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Then, you need only learn how to output as JSON and use `jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DazWilkin suggested I created an issue at the public google issue tracker here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161833506

The Cloud SDK engineering team is looking into this, however there is no ETA.